# I'm interested in the state-of-the-art of vocal sound synthesis. Please advise me

Tags: signal-analysis, algorithms, speech-processing, voice, signal-synthesis

Some of the things I'd like to accomplish:

- Strip the vocals from a recorded song as best as possible
- Recreate someone's song voice (like a famous artists') using someone else's voice as input
- Adjust parameters of the algorithm to slightly modify the output voice

What math, algorithms, research is out there?  Or is the above impossible?